# Получение частоты звука

Tags: java, android, аудио

Вот у меня есть `.3gpp` файл, и я знаю путь к нему в виде `String`. Аудио дорожку надо разбить на несколько частей, и получить среднее значение частоты к каждой части. Было бы круто, если был метод на подобии `int getFrequency(String path, int milliseconds)`, но точно такого метода я не нашел. Погуглив, я понял, что надо как-то декодировать аудио файл и сделать ряд вычислений, но непонятно каких вычислений и непонятно как декодировать аудио

Comment: А средняя частота это как? Есть вот в сигнале 440 Гц с высокой амплитудой и шумы от 20 Гц до 18000 Гц с низкой амплитудой. Что должно получиться-то?

Comment: Наверное, так как тюнер для муз. инструментов - показывать одну частоту.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Например, у нас есть кусок аудиофайла, который длится 1 секунду. Мы 100 раз отмеряем частоту, с промежутком в 10 миллисекунд, складываем все частоты и делим на 100

Comment: @Minebot Быстрое преобразование фурье используйте, короче. Только вы получите трэш с таким подходом. Потому что одновременно может быть больше 1 частоты, и часть из них может быть шумами...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Можно же не считать диапазон частот шума. Или же как-то сгладить их. Как может быть больше 1 частоты?

Comment: @Minebot Музыкант нажал две клавиши на пианино и звучит 440 Гц и 880Гц одновременно. А если он нажал три...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов А разве алгоритм сжатия аудио после записи не складывает эти частоты в одну? Или они записываются отдельно? Ладн, с алгоритмом понятно, но с кодом что? Как получить данные аудио файла, зная только путь к нему?

Answer (score 7):

Делается это так.

### Сначала чуть-чуть теории

Звук в общем (и в частности музыкальный) это сложение разных частот (по научному гармоник) с разной амплитудой. Если грубо представить то это иллюстрируется картинкой типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разбивка на частоты конкретного звука производится [преобразованием Фурье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5) - в вычислительном смысле это удобно делать т.н. [быстрым преобразованием Фурье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5)

В итоге мы получим табличку типа (*):

```
частота[i] -> амплитуда[i]
частота[i+1] -> амплитуда[i+1]
....
```

Далее вычисляем среднюю амплитуду то есть надо проинтегрировать табличку в слышимом диапазоне (от 20 гц. до 20 кгц) примерно так:

```
 сумма((частота[i+1]-частота[i])*амплитуда[i])/(20000-20)
```

Средняя громкость (пропорциональна логарифму амплитуды звука):

```
 сумма((частота[i+1]-частота[i])*log(амплитуда[i]))/(20000-20)
```

Средняя частота, это частота на которой интеграл:

```
 сумма((частота[i+1]-частота[i])*log(амплитуда[i]))
```

равен половине суммы за весь слышимый интервал. Иллюстрирует такая картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Теперь конкретнее

В обычном аудио файле/треке данные звука хранятся в виде PCM (pulse code modulation) - то есть это развертка звука по амплитуде и времени.

Вам надо получить эти данные из трека. В обычном Java это можно получить через `AudioInputStream`, но в Android он не работает. К счастью есть такая библиотека [RingDroid](https://github.com/google/ringdroid) - откуда можно почерпнуть это тайное знание.

Остается дело за малым засунуть за определенный интервал PCM данные в быстрое фурье, получить распределение и вычислить среднюю частоту.

Как то так.